# How to convert a string to date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, date

I have a *string* column which acts as a *date* and I want to select it as a `DATE`.

Is it possible?

My sample data format would be:

> `month/day/year` -> `12/31/2011`

Answer (score 309, accepted):

As was told at [MySQL Using a string column with date text as a date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908394/mysql-using-a-string-column-with-date-text-as-a-date-field), you can do

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM    yourtable
```

You can also handle these date strings in `WHERE` clauses. For example

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM yourtable
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

You can handle all kinds of date/time layouts this way. Please refer to [the format specifiers for the `DATE_FORMAT()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to see what you can put into the second parameter of `STR_TO_DATE()`.

Comment: I think it should be  INTERVAL 7 DAY instead of DAYS

Comment: I have a char column like "dd-mmm-yyyy" format. How do i query into "dd-mm-yyyy" format?

Comment: how about if the format is June 16, 2023 02:00 PM ? It does not work in my case....

Answer (score 61):

```
STR_TO_DATE('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: What is date is stored as DD/MM/YYYY format like 31/11/1015 ?

Comment: @VipulHadiya change the date format string to `%d/%m/%Y` like so `STR_TO_DATE('31/11/1015', '%d/%m/%Y')` Keep in mind the output will be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format as a `DATE`  data type.

Comment: code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow.  Please improve this correct answer.

Answer (score 18):

Here's another two examples.

To output the day, month, and year, you can use:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('14/02/2015', '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Which produces:

> 2015-02-14

To also output the time, you can use:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('14/02/2017 23:38:12', '%d/%m/%Y %T');
```

Which produces:

> 2017-02-14 23:38:12

Answer (score 12):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
use the above page to refer more Functions in MySQL

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(StringColumn, '%d-%b-%y')
FROM    table
```

say for example use the below query to get output

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('23-feb-14', '%d-%b-%y') FROM table
```

For String format use the below link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 7):

The following illustrates the syntax of the `STR_TO_DATE()` function:

```
STR_TO_DATE(str,fmt);
```

The `STR_TO_DATE()` converts the str string into a date value based on the fmt format string. The `STR_TO_DATE()` function may return a **DATE** , **TIME**, or **DATETIME** value based on the input and format strings. If the input string is illegal, the `STR_TO_DATE()` function returns NULL.

The following statement converts a string into a **DATE** value.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');
```

[image]

Based on the format string *‘%d, %m, %Y’*, the `STR_TO_DATE()` function scans the *‘21,5,2013’* input string.

- First, it attempts to find a match for the %d format specifier, which
  is a day of the month (01…31), in the input string. Because the
  number 21 matches with the %d specifier, the function takes 21 as the
  day value.
- Second, because the comma (,) literal character in the format string
  matches with the comma in the input string, the function continues to
  check the second format specifier %m , which is a month (01…12), and
  finds that the number 5 matches with the %m format specifier. It
  takes the number 5 as the month value.
- Third, after matching the second comma (,), the `STR_TO_DATE()`
  function keeps finding a match for the third format specifier %Y ,
  which is four-digit year e.g., 2012,2013, etc., and it takes the
  number 2013 as the year value.

The `STR_TO_DATE()` function ignores extra characters at the end of the input string when it parses the input string based on the format string. See the following example:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21,5,2013 extra characters','%d,%m,%Y');
```

[image]

More Details : [Reference](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/#:%7E:text=Introduction%20to%20MySQL%20STR_TO_DATE%20function&text=The%20STR_TO_DATE()%20converts%20the,STR_TO_DATE()%20function%20returns%20NULL.)