# How to get string as date in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a table that keeps `date` and `hour` data as string. I added two fields `date2` and `hour2` in order to convert and save current string instead of varchar. Date format is **`dd.mm.YYYY`**. I want to convert that string to date format and keep it in corresponding column for each row.

[image: Data table structure]
[image: Data table sample data]

I have read ["how to convert a string to date in mysql?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql) tried to query the following statement:

```
UPDATE `rawdata` SET `date2` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

but I still see `NULL` values in the `date2` column. Nothing is updated.

Comment: why not use one field as `datetime` to store `date2` and `hour2` into one field?

Comment: @amaster507, because there are different date formats in the records. Some are mm-dd-yy, some are dd.mm.yyyy, and else mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `STR_TO_DATE()` function's second parameter specifies the format of the date that you are giving it as a string which in your case does not match the format that is currently in your database. Try using:

```
UPDATE `rawdata` SET `date2` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: Now I see that I have misunderstood the date format. It is current date column's format. But I thought it was desired format. Thank you. that's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `rawdata` SET `date2` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

should be according to [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
UPDATE `rawdata` SET `date2` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

The second parameter, `format`, corresponds to how your string is currently formatted, not the format of MySQL date.

Alternatively I would combine `date2` and `hour2` into a datetime field using the following:

```
UPDATE `rawdata` SET `datetime2` = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`date`,'.',`hour`), '%d.%m.%Y.%H:%i')
```

That is of course after creating `datetime2` field with datetime data type.

Comment: Your format is in the wrong order from the data provided in the question.

Comment: @BadWolf thanks, I am so not use to using that format that I typed it out of habbit, fixed now.