# How to convert string to date in without knowing the string format

Tags: php, mysql

I know there is a [MySQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql) that converts string to date, but it requires the string format.

Is there a way to do it without knowing the format?

Or is there a way to get the format using PHP so that I can use it in MySQL?

Comment: Just curious, what date will `12/11/10` or `12/11/2010` represent in your hypothetical function?

Comment: Any reasons for downvoting?

Comment: As ansh01 noted, depending on the date given, you could have several different valid dates. Why do you need to do this? Do you really not know what format the date is provided in?

Comment: @ansh0l does not matter. This can be accepted as implementation specific.

Comment: @JoshMein date('Y-m-d', strtotime($string)) is an acceptable conversion without the API user knowing or actually finding out the format.

Comment: @Jake How are you deciding `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($string)) ` is acceptable? Why can't `date('m-d-Y', strtotime($string)) ` be the acceptable format?

Comment: @ansh0l I'd assume you guys are having a bad day, and I'll avoid getting into a debate that's not related to the question. Take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Do you mean this ?
SELECT unix_timestamp('2013-11-14'), 
unix_timestamp('2013/11/14'), 
unix_timestamp('13/11/14'), 
unix_timestamp('13-11-14'),
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('13-11-14'))

This will output 
1384358400 1384358400 1384358400 1384358400 "2013-11-14 00:00:00".
```

Comment: Thanks, that was close, but doesn't handle "true strings" like strtotime does.

Answer (score 1):

use strtotime() function of php, hope it may help go through below link.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I hope to do it in SQL.

Comment: I'd negate the downvote for you just to say explain that my question is valid if it were asking for a PHP method.