# Coverting a string into timestamp java mysql

Tags: java, mysql, csv, timestamp

My csv file has the following format `26/02/2014 17:20:17`. I've stored it in a string array in my program as value[0].

How would I go about converting it into a **timestamp** that can be stored into a **DATETIME** column in **mysql** e.g. `2014-02-26 17:20:17`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are working with date formats.

In java you can get a date object by using SimpleDateFormat.

```
public java.sql.Date convert(String value) throws Exception {
   return new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss").parse(value).getTime());
}
```

Note:
Throwing a general exception is a bad practice
SimpleDateFormat is expensive to create so try to cache the formatter to be used repetitively.
Also SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe

You can set the sql date into your prepared statement.