# MySQL - Convert INT to DATE format.

Tags: php, mysql, date, int

How I can convert INT to date in php and than find this date in mysql table ?

Lets say I want to convert

```
$month = (int)$_GET['month'];
$month = 42014 ;//This means 04th month in 2014 year
$month = 04-2014; // I want this
```

And than find that in mysql table

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM matches WHERE date=$month");// This need to select
                                                               // all data that is
                                                               // created in 04th month
                                                               // of 2014 year .



echo "Thanks :)";
```

Comment: What is the `var_dump($_GET['month']);` ?

Comment: string(6) "042014" // but getting some other errors also

Comment: For `42014` date value you can use `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m%Y')='$month'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass `$month` parameter like you do.

Send and pass both `$month` and `$year` and handle them after:

```
$month = (int)$_GET['month'];
$year = (int)$_GET['year'];
if($month < 10) { // add this check for months lesser then october (they containt 1 digit, which is wrong for t-sql)
    $month = "0".$month;
}
$query=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM matches WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datefield, '%m-%Y') = '$month-$year'");
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201403/2898694)

If you can't send both month and year in different variables, do this, like [M Khalid Junaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/853360/m-khalid-junaid) suggested:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM matches WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datefield,'%m%Y')='$month'");
```

Comment: You are welcome. Sure, you can use M Khalid Junaid method, but I think better is to send both month and year. Choose what is better for you.

Comment: I just made to send both separately but its not working with this query . This is how i done: SELECT date, home, away, pick, stake, odd, rezultat, moguci_dobitak, user, analiza FROM matches WHERE u_id='$id11' AND STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%Y') = '$month'-'$year' ORDER BY date DESC ... But its not working , when i remove "AND STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%Y') = '$month'-'$year'" its working but not selecting correct date range .. any help ?

Comment: @MHB http://sqlfiddle.com/ create here your mysql scheme and give me a link. Or just add your sql scehem (t-sql query for creating table) to your question.

Comment: I dont know how to create schema for my table (am novice) but however i uploaded matches table.sql here : http://www.speedyshare.com/bVaYM/matches-1.sql .. if this helps ? thanks

Comment: Check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba0962/1 This is an example. Answer is updated. Hope, I helped you now.

Comment: I made it , and its working ...I made it as @M Khalid Junaid said WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m%Y')='$month' .. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Well, I suggested same, but with two variables. It is better anyway, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Try as below using **[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)**

```
$month = $_GET['month'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mY',$month);
echo $date->format('m-Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$input=42014;
$year = strlen(substr($input,-4));
$month = substr(0,(strlen($input)-strlen($year)));
$final = $month."-".$year
```