# Convert a string to date in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

Can the MYSQL function STR-TO-DATE convert a string in this format 99-MMM-9999 (ex., '21-Sep-2014' to a date format?  And what if that field is defined as 12 chars instead of the specific 11?

I tried this and it got NULLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can, just setting proper format mask:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21-Sep-2014','%d-%M-%Y');
```

If you have 12 chars, set proper mask, sample:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(' 21-Sep-2014',' %d-%M-%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y')
    FROM    yourtable
```

You can also handle these date strings in WHERE clauses. For example

```
    SELECT whatever
  FROM yourtable
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAYS
```

You can handle all kinds of date / time layouts this way. Please refer to the format specifiers for the DATE_FORMAT() function to see what you can put into the second parameter to STR_TO_DATE()

reference :- [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Thanks - I found my key mistake was that I should have been using '%b' to tell it was an abbreviated month., ex, Jan, Feb, etc,

Comment: @DaveL Is the answer Useful for You if yes then Please Accept the answer