# mysql WHERE BETWEEN by date return incorrect results?

Tags: mysql

I have a table look like this :

```
match_name   match_formatted_date
A vs B       28.10.2014
b vs c       26.10.2014
c vs d       18.10.2014
d vs e       30.09.2014
e vs f       27.09.2014
g vs h       19.09.2014
h vs j       28.08.2014
x vs y       26.08.2014
y vs z       07.08.2014
```

mysql:

```
SELECT `m`.* FROM `match` `m` 
WHERE (m.match_formatted_date BETWEEN "24.10.2014" AND "31.10.2014")  
ORDER BY `m`.`match_id` DESC
```

But mysql return values look like this:

```
A vs B       28.10.2014
b vs c       26.10.2014
d vs e       30.09.2014
e vs f       27.09.2014
h vs j       28.08.2014
x vs y       26.08.2014
```

I only want to get this :

```
A vs B       28.10.2014
b vs c       26.10.2014
```

note : match_formatted_date is varchar, not datetime . whether it is a problem or not?

Comment: Convert/cast `match_formatted_date` into Date and use proper date notation for range boundaries.

Comment: "note : match_formatted_date is varchar, not datetime . whether it is a problem or not?", yes... That would be a problem.

Comment: Or keep the date in format YYYY-MM-DD (or use dots instead of dashes) if you do not want to store date in corresponding field type. This will allow to make string comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert both column and search string to date type:

```
SELECT `m`.* `match` `m` 
WHERE (str_to_date(m.match_formatted_date, '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN str_to_date("24.10.2014", '%d.%m.%Y') AND str_to_date("31.10.2014", '%d.%m.%Y'))  
ORDER BY `m`.`match_id` DESC
```

Comment: too fast too furious :)) . your code run perfectly . Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0):

Right now you were comparing strings with your `BETWEEN` clause, which basically led to comparing only the days of the date. You can see, that all returned rows have days between 24 and 31.

Use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert your string to a proper date value that can be compared against:

```
SELECT `m`.*
FROM `match` `m` 
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(m.match_formatted_date,'%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('24.10.2014','%d.%m.%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31.10.2014','%d.%m.%Y')  
ORDER BY `m`.`match_id` DESC
```

Read about that here: [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)