# How to pick the 1 st and last element of each group in a table during group by operation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table where i have some data and i am doing a group by operation on those data set. I.I am doing the group by operation using date , like i have my first and last column as date so my first column is date and last column is previous Sunday of that date,so which dates have same previous Sunday will belong to a group .So i am doing the group by by previous Sunday .Now my requirement is ,when i am doing group by i have need to show starting date and ending date of that group i am column. I am posting my table structure  below ,

```
 DateAdded  Souring Inake placement  PreviousSunday 
'22 Jan 2015'   2     4       6      '2015-01-18'
'23 Jan 2015'   5     6       8      '2015-01-18'
'24 Jan 2015'   8     7       6      '2015-01-18'
'26 Jan 2015'   6     1       9      '2015-01-25'
'27 Jan 2015'   8     56      0      '2015-01-25'
```

...........................................
and so on .
so my 1st 3 rows have  their previous Sunday common,so they belong o a group.next two also have their previous Sunday common.so In my output what i want to show like

```
DateAdded  Souring Inake placement  PreviousSunday DateStartEnd 
'22 Jan 2015'   2     4       6      '2015-01-18'  '22 Jan 2015' - '24 Jan 2015'  
'26 Jan 2015'   6     1       9      '2015-01-25'  '26 Jan 2015' - '27 Jan 2015'
```

How to achieve that ?? someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, assuming that your `DateAdded` is a date and you can rely on it for ordering or for using `MAX()`:

```
select s.DateAdded, s.Souring, s.Inake, s.placement, s.PreviousSunday, CONCAT(s.DateAdded, ' => ', e.DateEnd) as DateStartEnd
from table_name as s 
inner join (select MAX(DateAdded) as DateEnd, PreviousSunday from table_name group by PreviousSunday) as e on s.PreviousSunday = e.PreviousSunday
group by e.DateEnd
order by s.DateAdded
```

If `DateAdded` is a string (why?) you should combine this query with `STR_TO_DATE()` like it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql).

Comment: @ eillarra I don't want to show the previous sunday in the output i want to show the start index and the end index of the group see my required output

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want by converting the `dateAdded` value to a real date and then using `min()` and `max()`:

```
select min(dateAdded), min(souring), min(inake), min(placement), previousSunday
       concat(min(str_to_date(dateAdded, '%d %b %Y)), '-', min(str_to_date(dateAdded, '%d %b %Y)))
from table t
group by previousSunday;
```

This does change the format (you can use `date_format()` to control that).  The more important question is why you are storing dates as strings in your database.  You should use the appropriate type.

Comment: Not sure about the use of `MIN()` here. Using `MIN()`, `placement` will be `0` for 26 Jan 2015, and not `9` as shown in the question.

Comment: `select min(str_to_date(DateAdded, '%d %b %Y')) as DateAdded, Souring, Inake, placement, PreviousSunday, concat(min(str_to_date(dateAdded, '%d %b %Y')), ' => ', max(str_to_date(DateAdded, '%d %b %Y'))) as DateStartEnd
from t
group by PreviousSunday` will be a corrected version of your query, that, by the way, looks cleaner than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

remember to replace instances of mytable with your actual table name. I have assumed that the columns are named after what you provided.

```
SELECT MIN(DateAdded), 
(SELECT Souring FROM mytable WHERE DateAdded = mt.DateAdded) AS Souring ,
(SELECT Inake FROM mytable WHERE DateAdded = mt.DateAdded) AS Inake, 
(SELECT Placement FROM mytable WHERE DateAdded = mt.DateAdded) AS     Placement,
MAX(PreviousSunday), Concat(DateAdded, " - ", MAX(DateAdded))     DateStartEnd
FROM mytable mt GROUP BY PreviousSunday
```

Comment: If this is the case, it means that you must be having same values for the DateAdded column. To get around this, you can change the sub queries to compare using a unique key such as ID, that is if your table has one. i.e.
Change all occurrences of  "WHERE DateAdded = mt.DateAdded" to be something like "WHERE ID = mt.ID.

Comment: If there is a more than one row error, it means that you have the ame DateAdded value appearing in more than one row. In this case, you could use a more unique field (Such as ID if it exists in your table) to prevent the error. You can achieve this by changing three "WHERE DateAdded = mt.DateAdded" clauses to be something like "WHERE ID = mt.ID"