# MySQL comparing stored date with current date and execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have stored dates (dd/mm/yyyy) in text format in a `table` in a field called `dates`. I want to compare those dates with the current date and if the dates are smaller (if the dates have passed) to move the entire row into a new table called `archive`. Tried something with the `DATEDIFF()` but I'm new to MySQL and can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: First, stop storing dates as a string (char/varchar/text) and start storing it as a date.  There is a reason for the DATE column type.  Then see if you still need to ask this question.

Comment: Look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community! We're looking forward to your contribution to the site! [**What should I do when someone answers my question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to preface my answer with a short remark: storing "date" values in SQL database in VARCHAR columns is an anti-pattern. MySQL provides native datatype `DATE` which is designed to handle "date" values. But that's just a remark, doesn't answer your question.

---

You can use the convenient MySQL **`STR_TO_DATE`** function to convert strings into `DATE` values. For example:

```
STR_TO_DATE('15/05/2015','%d/%m/%Y')
```

You could use a column reference in place of the literal, e.g.

```
STR_TO_DATE(t.mycharcol,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

and that will return a `DATE` value you can compare to another `DATE` value, using the standard inequality operator `<` for example.

To return the current date from the database, you can use an expression such as

```
DATE(NOW())
```

Putting that together, you could write a query like this:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM t
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(t.mycharcol,'%d/%m/%Y') < DATE(NOW())
```

If you want to take the result from a SELECT statement and insert those rows into another table, you can use the **`INSERT ... SELECT`** form of the `INSERT` statement.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

---

Beware of the behavior with badly formatted or invalid dates, e.g.

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('35/05/2015','%d/%m/%Y')
      , STR_TO_DATE('15-05-2015','%d/%m/%Y')
```