# How to balance out row mode and column mode in cygnus?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have a weather-station that transmits data each hour. During that hour it makes four recordings (one every 15 minutes). In my current situation I am using `attr_persistence=row` to store data in my MySql database.

With row mode I get the default generated columns:

```
recvTimeTs | recvTime | entityId | entityType | attrName | attrType | attrValue | attrMd
```

But my weather station sends me the following data:

```
 |   attrName    | attrValue

   timeRecorded   14:30:0,22.5.2015
   measurement1   18.799
   measurement2   94.0
   measurement3   1.19
```

These attrValue are represented in the database as string.

Is there a way to leave the three measurements in row mode and switch the timeRecorded to column mode? And if not, then what is my alternative?

The point of all this is to query the time recorded value, but I cannot query date as long as it is string.

As a side note: having the weather station send the data as soon as it is recorded (every 15 minutes) is out of the question, firstly because I need to conserve battery power and more importantly because in the case of a problem with the post, it will send all of the recordings at once.

So if an entire day went without sending any data, the weather station will send all 24*4 readings at once...

Comment: I need you elaborate a bit more on your question, please. How do you send the 4 measurements in a single Orion notification? Are you using 4 different attributes? Or a single multi-valued attribute? BTW, are they 4 measures or 3, as you are describing in the example?

Comment: Regarding the TimeRecorded value, you can translate it to a MySQL Timestamp by using MySQL functions such as `STR_TO_DATE`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql

Comment: @frb I am using 4 different attributes: the three measurements and the time recorded.

Comment: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE( attrValue,  '%m/%d/%Y' ) 
FROM  ``def_servpath_0004_weatherstation`` ` 

@frb I just tried that script and it always yields a NULL, maybe because it actually IS a date at every fourth place.

Comment: OK, 3 measures... just to warn you: 3 measures will only cover 45' minutes o an entire hour :) I mean, you will have measures for 16:15, 16:30 and 16:45, and from 16:45 to :17:15 you have a gap o 30'. Anyway, this is not important from the question point of view.

Comment: I misunderstood you question, I meant that for each of the FOUR measurements in an hour, the weather station sends those FOUR attributes. But it sends all four measurements separately! one after the other. Hope we are clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution is to use the `STR_TO_DATE` function of MySQL in order to translate the stored string-based "timeRecorded" attribute into a real MySQL Timestamp type.

Nevertheless, "timeRecorded" attribute appears every 4 rows in the table due to the "row" attribute persistence mode of `OrionMySQLSink`. In this case I think you can use the `ROWNUM` keyword from MySQL in order to get only every 4 rows, something like (not an expert on MySQL):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( attrValue, '%m/%d/%Y' ) FROM def_servpath_0004_weatherstation where (ROWNUM / 4 = 0);
```

The alternative is to move to "column" mode (in this case you have to provision de table by yourself). By using this mode you will have a single row with all the 4 attributes, being one of these attributes the "timeRecorded" one. In this case, you can provision the table by directly specifying the type of the "timeRecorded" column as Timestamp, instead of Text. That way, you will avoid the `STR_TO-DATE` part.

Comment: your answer makes sense, but it wont work in my example for some reason. I tried converting the following formats from string to date but they all yield NULL:
`2015-04-30T16:50:42.87` and `15:15:0,30.4.2015`