# mysql: between not working with date

Tags: mysql, date, between

I am Writing a Between query with formatted date..
This is my query:

---

> SELECT shop_id, date_format(registered_time,'%d-%m-%Y') as Date FROM
>   shops where (date_format(registered_time,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN
>   '09-03-2016' AND '19-04-2016')

---

However, when I execute query, it gives my only the records between date 09 and 19 regardless of month.
For example, I have records like **30-03-2016, 31-03-2016**..but they are ignored.

If anyone can find anything out of this, please tell me..

One more thing is that, I am converting this date from time stamp field. I hope that isn't causing any issues.

Comment: You are comparing strings not dates. And '30..' is **not** between '09..' and '19..'.

Comment: I am using the same format to compare results there is no issue in it. What dates you have in the table column

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn your strings back into dates that MySQL understands. From the documentation:

```
CAST(datetime_col AS DATE)
```

should help accomplish what you want.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html)

Comment: `CAST()` is unlikely to understand the `DD-MM-YYYY` format though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't take two arbitrary strings (like `30-03-2016`) and expect `BETWEEN` to behave like it would for real `DATE` columns (a behaviour that is hard-coded into mySQL).

You need to use real `DATE` values for `BETWEEN` to work properly.

- If the columns are already `DATE` columns, just skip the formatting:

  ```
  SELECT shop_id, registered_time FROM shops where registered_time 
  BETWEEN '2016-03-09' AND '2016-04-19'
  ```

If your existing columns are in the `DD-MM-YYYY` format, convert them to dates using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql) - either on the fly just for the purposes of this query (sloooowwwww!) or permanently.

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn your "registered_time" string date back to date as follow.

**STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(registered_time,'%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y')  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('09-03-2016','%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('19-04-2016','%d/%m/%Y')**

This worked for me.