# SQL "BETWEEN" request not acting as I want

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I'm having some issues with my SQL request.

Here's the request :

```
SELECT SUBSTR(`Date`, 1, 11) AS `format_date` 
FROM table 
HAVING `format_date` BETWEEN '07/06/2016' AND '16/06/2016'
```

When I run the request I get not wanted results like *"07/11/2014"*. After doing some tests it looks like the request is only taking the day in consideration but I can't really figure out why. Any ideas ?

Comment: What data type is your date column?

Comment: The type is varchar. The DBMS is Phpmyadmin

Comment: Do ***NOT*** store dates in `VARCHAR` columns. Ever.

Comment: Looks like a valid text comparison to me, you might want to compare the day, month and year of the two dates manually to ensure correct date semantic.

Comment: Change the data type to  `date`. THAT is the only real solution

Comment: The reason why its varchar is because the datas come from a Excel file, I guess the default is always varchar. However, when I try to convert into Date it doesn't work. The format of my dates are : dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm:ss (I'm french)

Comment: @Smutje Sorry to say, but I don't think that comment's very helpful.

Comment: I'm Australian dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss is my "normal" aussi, BUT that format a poor choice when doing comparisons or trying to sort the data. YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss would be better. Truly you do need to store dates as dates, not text. Using between for date ranges is `NOT` best practice either. MySQL has moved to sub-second time precision in recent versions so it's time to learn how to use >= and < for more accurate date range selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`07/11/2014`is between the two given strings. You are comparing strings, not dates, but you are getting exactly what you ask for.

This is what you compare:

> "07/0" < **"07/1"** < "16/0"

Try comparing actual dates, or format your string so that you can use them (YYYY/MM/DD).

This question (and its accepted answer) should help you convert your strings to useable dates:
[how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

You can then copmpare real dates with each other.

Comment: Alright, I see whats wrong. But I'm not sure what method to use in order to change my dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd. Could you help ?

Comment: @coco I added a link to the relevant question on SO to convert your strings to dates.

Answer (score 1):

The reason what you get wrong result is clear already, you can try following;)

```
SELECT SUBSTR(`Date`, 1, 11) AS `format_date` 
FROM table 
HAVING STR_TO_DATE(`format_date`, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('07/06/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('16/06/2016', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

And I think you should change `HAVING` to `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be summed up in the following expression...

```
SELECT '8' BETWEEN '7' AND '77';
+--------------------------+
| '8' BETWEEN '7' AND '77' |
+--------------------------+
|                        0 |
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems to address.

1. The simplest is that you have wrongly used HAVING instead of WHERE.
2. You have converted dates into strings in the form dd/mm/yyyy. The problem here is that text (strings) do NOT  behave like numbers e.g. in text 1 and 10 are sorted before 2 or 3. Due to this you are asking for TEXT between STRINGS THAT LOOK LIKE DATES but it will not behave thay way because it requires handling dates as numeric.
3. Between is a very poor way to handle date ranges. A far more reliable way is to use a combination of >= and < as seen below.

Example

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Date, 1, 11) AS `format_date` 
FROM table 
WHERE `date` >= '2016-06-06'' AND `date` < '2016-06-17'
```