# how to convert datetime automatically from 00/00/0000 00:00:00 format to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 format on CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, datetime, import

I have the following csv

```
January,December,,,Blaize,Wildsights,Blaize,Wildsights,61,1,30,,,,,,,,,,10/09/2013 20:10:52,10/09/2013 20:11:05
January,December,,,Michael,Wildsights,Michael,Wildsights,61,2,31,,,,,,,,,,10/09/2013 20:11:03,10/09/2013 20:11:05
........
....
..
```

After importing it using phpmyadmin I saw that the timestamps have not been imported.

[image]

If it is not possible to keep the timestamps as 00/00/0000 00:00:00 how can I convert datetime automaticaly from 00/00/0000 00:00:00 format to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 format on CSV. I have thousand rows

Comment: it depends a great deal on precisely how you are importing.

Comment: I click "import" then, I click "choose file" I select the csv file ( first two colomns are shown above ). then I just click "Go".

Comment: This is probably possible if you use `LOAD DATA`.

Comment: so, this is a phpmyadmin question, not a mysql question.

Comment: @MikeNakis Agree, but phpmyadmin may not be perfect for all use cases.

Comment: phpmyadmin is just a tool I tried to use mysql front and heidi didn't work either. I guess I have to convert 10/09/2013 20:10:52 to 2013-09-10 20-10-52 how can I do it I have thousands rows

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a `tempDate` column of `NVARCHAR` type to your mySql database.
2. import your CSV telling phpmyadmin to import your problematic dates into the `tempDate` column instead of your actual date column.  This will succeed, because `tempDate` is `NVARCHAR`, so it will accept anything.
3. Consult this: [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql) on how to execute an `UPDATE` statement on your database to populate your actual date column from the `tempDate` column.
4. remove the `tempDate` column.