# How to ASC DESC Date which data type is varchar

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do can I asc date?
I have the folllowing in sql

```
2014-3-18
2014-1-15
2014-3-20
2015-3-18
```

I tried the ff codes but it just gives me error in my db.
And yes the data type of the column is varchar.
And also there's NULL values in that column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `locate` 
ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(DateTime, `Date`,101)  DESC
```

Please help. Thanks! :)

Comment: Which DBMS DO you use?

Comment: Also add the error message if you get an error

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`Date`,101)  DESC LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4

Comment: remove `` while selecting the database name and also while converting.

Comment: xampp is not a database. Your query Looks like mssql i guess you use mysql

Comment: Mysql based `CONVERT` takes 2 parameters at max, why do you have the third one there?

Comment: Change your datatype to a native date or datetime datatype

Comment: if you are using mysql, use `str_to_date(your_date_column, '%Y/%m/%d')`

Comment: `CONVERT(columnName, DATE)`

Comment: @MonPadi Add the error message to your question using the EDIT function. Not as a comment

Comment: See the Edit button

Comment: **(1)** You mention that you're getting an error but cannot be bothered to state the _error message_. Understanding _error messages_ is half the problem solved - it's ***not*** some sort of "state secret"! **(2)** Don't store dates as strings, and you won't have to deal with convertion and the resultant errors. **(3)** If you do store as strings, use "yyyy-mm-dd" (NB Month and day padded to 2 digits; year to 4.) Then the string ordering and date ordering will be identical - again avoiding the need for any error prone conversion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Comment: Yep possible duplicate. But that article doesn't have the ORDER BY so in case there are dummies(like me) search this kind of query. This can helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you use mysql so you can not use the `mssql` `convert` function. you have to use `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `locate` 
ORDER BY 
   STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%Y-%m-%d')  DESC
```

For more Information see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Thank you! I need some basics between mssql and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Use the order by this way :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') as date_formatted
FROM locate 
ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Lets hear from the author if it works or not. If not we can find an alternative.

Comment: ofcourse will not work -)) because s/he uses xampp - which is  a apache, mysql, php/perl/python bundle.

Comment: That works too. But it does not show the other column's values. It just shows the date. I already found the solution below.

Comment: only date is selected so it shows that. You can select other columns by adding " , " . Hope this helps. Please upvote if it helped.

Comment: that can be another way to handle this use case

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing **EventDate** is a char or varchar and not a date otherwise your order by clause would be fine.

You can use CONVERT to change the values to a date and sort by that

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
     vw_view 
ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(DateTime, EventDate,101)  DESC
```

The problem with that is, as Sparky points out in the comments, if EventDate has a value that can't be converted to a date the query won't execute.

This means you should either exclude the bad rows or let the bad rows go to the bottom of the results

To exclude the bad rows just add **WHERE IsDate(EventDate) = 1**

To let let the bad dates go to the bottom you need to use **CASE**

e.g.

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE
       WHEN IsDate(EventDate) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DateTime, EventDate,101)
       ELSE null
    END DESC
```