# How to use greater than operator in mysql query with date which is in the type varchar

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table `task` with fields

```
tid int(10),
sdate varchar(25), -- `30-08-2017`
tname varchar(30)`
```

I want to select details from the table with following condition.
Here is my sql query.

```
Select * from task where sdate < '07-09-2017';
```

But I can't get any records with this condition.
Please any other solution for this issue...Thanks to all in advance

Comment: If `sdate` is used to store date values, then, instead of using `varchar`, you should use one of the types available in MySQL for this kind of data, like `datetime`.

Comment: By converting string to date in MySQL using STR_TO_DATE function, here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql. Another approach is by DATE_FORMAT function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better idea to change your `column` data type to `DateTime` or what ever your need than using a `query` like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM task
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(sdate, '%d-%m-%Y') < STR_TO_DATE('07-09-2017', '%d-%m-%Y');
```