# Get 5 days back records with specific date formate with mysql

Tags: mysql, database, type-conversion

I want to select records of 5 days ago with mysql, but the problem is that my date column is varchar and in the following format yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 AM/PM.

How can I convert this date format to mysql date and select records from 5 days back?

my date column name is 'date_time'

Comment: You should not store dates as varchar, you should store them as datetime. That is why that datatype exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Comment: @SeanLange you are right, its a very old table, at that time I didn't know about mysql default date type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a job for `STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Try this.

```
 ... WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p')) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

The `'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p'` [DATE_FORMAT() string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) matches your textual date format.

This will never be fast if you have to search through a large number of rows, because it isn't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). It can't exploit an index.

Comment: Appreciate it mate, it does exactly what I wanted.