# Convert CHAR to date in mysql

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I am trying to compare a year stored as CHAR(4) to a year stored as DATETIME, but every time I try to convert the CHAR year to a date, I always get NULL when I expect the year in format 'YYYY'. I've read the formatting for using str_to_date, but I'm not sure why it always comes out as null (maybe I've misread something). Must the string/format in the str_to_date function be full dates and not just a year format?

```
SELECT id, STR_TO_DATE(year, '%Y') AS Year
FROM elite_years
LIMIT 100;
```

Most if not all the data in the elite_years table is a four character year (e.g. '2008'). I can't modify the datatypes in the table either.
I am using the Yelp Dataset fyi.

I checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql), but from what I could see, I am following the correct formatting which I based off of [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: Do it the other way round?  convert the char to int and compare with YEAR(dt_fld)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but do you have any idea as to why my previous method wasn't working?

Comment: I'm suspicious of those backticks around `%Y`

Comment: I tried it with   ' , ` , and  ".
Only the backtick returns error and the other two bring NULL. I typed it wrong here, I had just a single quote in my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Comment: YEAR(year) as Year

Comment: @Roy, I've already found an alternate solution thanks to Alex K., I'm just looking for a rational as to why it would keep returning NULL.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, no. That question is asking for the existence of a str_to_date function, which I am using. My question is trying to understand why the function could return NULL when I am following the correct format (but probably not somehow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse a string using `STR_TO_DATE()`, there needs to be enough information in the string to uniquely identify a date. A year alone isn't enough -- you still need a month and day, in some form or another.

This is hinted at in the warning you get when you try:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2009', '%Y') \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
str_to_date('2009', '%Y'): NULL
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1411
Message: Incorrect datetime value: '2009' for function str_to_date
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```