# Get latest record from database based on month and date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, xampp, sql-date-functions

I'm trying to get the latest record from a table based on the date. My date format is mm/yyyy. I've tried using MAX(date) but it's getting the record based on the month only. I've also tried using MONTH(MAX(date)) but returns a null value. Any help is much appreciated. By the way, I'm currently using XAMPP if that helps.

Comment: Can you share the create table statement, also add some sample data and desired output.

Comment: `mm/yyyy` is not a date. A date consists of a month, a day, and a year. What data type is your column?

Comment: Are you storing a date as a varchar? Yuck! Fix this ASAP!

Comment: I'm required to use the mm/yyyy format so I'm using VARCHAR as opposed to the DATE format which is MM/DD/YYYY @TheImpaler

Comment: So you're not using dates, so stop trying to use date-related functions to work with them. Date-related functions are designed to work with actual dates (month, day, year), and not some kludged-up VARCHAR value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates don't have formats.  In MySQL, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
order by right(date, 4) desc, left(date, 2) asc
limit 1;
```

You should learn to use the built-in data types for dates and date/times.

Comment: Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the string format to date format before filtering, you can refer to this post:

[how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with :

SELECT *
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
ORDER BY expression DESC;

The order expression will be date field name you want to order.