# How to convert string to date format in mysql ?

Tags: mysql

My date format looks like this '201710'. I'm trying to convert this particular string to '2017-10-01'.

How can I convert from the above mentioned format to the required format in mysql ?

I have tried using the below query:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(yymm,'%Y-%m-%d') AS niceDate 
FROM table;
```

But the niceDate column is showing null.

Can anyone please help me out ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I am new to SQL but i think you need to specify the column you want to format, for example im not sure on the exact code for your data but something like;

```
select *, DATE_FORMAT(yourdata, "%Y/%m/%d") as niceDate
from table;
```

Change "yourdata" to the date column you wish to format. Let me know if this helps, thanks :)

Comment: Hi has my solution given you any luck?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use STR_TO_DATE() funcion to convert string to date,
```

In your example you have not provide day part, you provide only year and month but for using this function your string should have year,month and day part
Example

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20171001','%Y%m%d') ;
```

Comment: I have tried using STR_TO_DATE() also. But, still the niceDate column is showing null

Comment: you have to provide date part also for this conversion

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to convert all the values of date field into the required format. Where I'm trying to add like this : SELECT STR_TO_DATE('date','%Y%m%d') from table; where 'date' is a column in my table.

Comment: @dev007 in that by using check date column made it complete  year,month and date  and then apply this function

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
  SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y') as 
    FROM    table
```

'yourdatefield' replace with your date column name.

Answer (score 0):

you can CONCAT your string / FIELD then you have a valid DATE

```
SELECT str_to_date(CONCAT('201710','01'),'%Y%m%d');
```

**SAMPLE**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT str_to_date(CONCAT('201710','01'),'%Y%m%d');
+---------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date(CONCAT('201710','01'),'%Y%m%d') |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 2017-10-01                                  |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```