# Converting string to timestamp format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sqlyog

I have a column in my MySQL database which has timestamp data in string format. I want to convert it into timestamp format.

Below is the sample data:

```
Date
--------------------------------
Fri Dec 14 14:11:43 IST 2018
Fri Dec 14 14:13:20 IST 2018
```

I'm expecting the result to be in the following format:

```
14-12-2018 14:11:43
14-12-2018 14:13:20
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert the string into a `DATETIME`, then by using `DATE_FORMAT()` can change it to the expected date time format.

The following query will return the expected output date time format:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(
         STR_TO_DATE('Fri Dec 14 14:11:43 IST 2018', '%a %b %d %T IST %Y'), 
       '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Output:

```
14-12-2018 14:11:43
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16c58098dd6ea4d10ff4ddece29023b8)

Reference formats are available in this [link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_format-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use str_to_date()

```
str_to_date('Fri Dec 14 14:11:43 IST 2018', '%a %b %d %T IST %Y');
```