# How to Fetch data related to current date from data base with date Time

Tags: mysql

My database date column format is (16/06/2019 8:33 AM). How can I fetch data based on current date only.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date_column = CURDATE()
```

Comment: What is the data type of date_column?

Comment: @Jens data type of date_column is text

Comment: So you have to convert the text to a date first. But you should not store dates as text. Use an date column to store dates.

Comment: @Jens i changed data type of date_column date, But its still not working. trying with bellow answer.

Comment: How have you changed it?

Comment: @Jens oh sorry that's why all my date-column is blank  now,  And its not inserting date format like 16/06/2019 8:33 AM, I am trying to insert it with `date('d/m/Y g:i A');`

Comment: You have to convert your string to date first with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE DATE(date_column) = CURDATE()
```