# select last month's data when the date column is a string

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I finding the sum of revenue last month. Currently, I'm filtering by giving where condition.
For example if I need last month's data given the current date is '20191111'. My query to get October's data is

```
Select sum(revenue)
from Table 1
where date between '20191001' and '20191031'
```

Note : My date column is a string. How can I modify it to fetch the last month's record automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Comment: How can I convert and use the converted date to get the last month's records

Comment: The best way to accomplish this is **fixing** the column (because the schema really is _broken_ right now) to use a date/datetime type instead of a string type.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: AWS Athena is the DB I'm using

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, although if your date column in the table is currently in String format, I would consider casting that column as a date data type, then using greater than and less than comparisons instead of the between clause.

Try something like the following:

```
SELECT SUM(revenue)
FROM Table 1
WHERE CAST(date AS DATE) >= '20191001' AND CAST(date AS DATE) < '20191101'
```

To fetch the last month's revenue automatically, or the total revenue for the month as of the current date, you could use something like the following:

Get the last months revenue:

```
SELECT SUM(revenue)
FROM Table 1
WHERE MONTH(CAST(date AS DATE)) < (MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1) 
AND MONTH(CAST(date AS DATE)) > (MONTH(GETDATE()) - 2)
```