# convert varchar datetime to datetime while selecting from sql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have one table with field name DateTime (varchar(30))  and I want to compare this field to the same date and time formate. 
Below is the ss what I am doing. I am getting some date NULL and date formate returning wrong I want M/D/Y H:i:s but it returns (11/09/19 12:32:40) to 2011-09-19 12:32:40

Can anyone please help me to get right date with DateTime in SQL select query. so, I can compare it.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share the table structure, sample input data, expected output, and your attempts

Comment: @NicoHaase I already put the type of the field and date formate and what result I want. There is no need to add whole database structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Comment: @Shefali SELECT CONVERT(varchar, '10/28/19 05:14:10 PM', 22);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), not `DATE_FORMAT`. For your dates, you need this format:

```
 %m/%d/%y %l:%i:%s %p
```

For example

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10/28/18 05:14:10 PM', '%m/%d/%y %l:%i:%s %p')
```

Output:

```
2018-10-28 17:14:10
```

Comment: Thanks, the right solution. I Forgot about this function.

Comment: I accepted this answer. Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CONVERT(datetime,getDate(),22);
```

Comment: Or you can check the reference here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/