# Query from database with date range in .Net Core

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I receive a MySql database and one table inside it have a Date column in string format, now I need to build a .Net core server with Pomelo and EF Core and requirement is my server can query data from that table in a range of date, but because Date column of that table is in string format so I don't know how to query it, please help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to get that string into a date in order to query it.

I would probably add a new datetime column to the table and then create a simple console app that reads in each string date, try to parse this as a datetime and save it to the new datetime column.

Then you should see how many rows have valid datetimes and correct the others

Finally, you can then query using Entity Framework

Comment: That a good idea, I though about it before but I'm scare that table have too many record so it can cause some unexpected process while convert, but I think I should try this solution, scare just a scare, thanks for your answer

Comment: @HuanNguyen if you are worried about this, take a copy and try it first. If something does go wrong, it doesn't matter as its just a copy

Answer (score 0):

[how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

As was told here

You can Query string to date

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM    yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks,I will try your solution but I have another question that if have a way that we can you LinQ and EF Core or we need to use raw SQL execution, btw thanks for your answer again

Answer (score 0):

### With database schema change

If you can (i.e. are allowed) to change the schema of the table in question, then just add a new `datetime` or `date` column, copy the data over from the old column to the new one, and drop the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `YourTable` ADD COLUMN `NewDateColumn` date NOT NULL;
UPDATE `YourTable` SET `NewDateColumn` = STR_TO_DATE(`OldDateColumn`,'%Y-%m-%d');
ALTER TABLE `YourTable` DROP COLUMN `OldDateColumn`;
```

You can run these statements just using MySQLWorkbench or the commmand line tool. Of course you first test them with a local copy, to see that everything works fine.

### With value converter

If you cannot change the schema of the table, then you can still query date ranges from the database, as long as the date strings in the database are in a string format, that sorts alphabetically (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD`). In that case, you can just use a [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) in your actual app code and don't need to alter the database at all:

```cs
public class SomeModel
{
    public int SomeModelId {get; set;}
    public DateTime YourDateProperty {get; set;} // <-- the type you want to use in .NET
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<SomeModel> SomeModels { get; set; }

    // ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SomeModel>(
            entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.YourDateProperty)
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(255)") // <-- the type it has in the database table
                    .HasConversion(
                        v => v.ToString(@"yyyy\-MM\-dd"),
                        v => DateTime.Parse(v, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            });
    }
}

// Here is how a sample query in your app would look like:
var query = context.SomeModels
    .Where(m => m.YourDateProperty >= new DateTime(2020, 9, 1) &&
                m.YourDateProperty < new DateTime(2020, 9, 10))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: awesome, thank you for your solutions, you save my day sir !

Comment: @HuanNguyen Glad I could help! If went with this answer, you should mark it as the solution.