# date interval in sql coding

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, case

I have a table like below:

```
Creationdate         Priority             interval
10/10/2020             P0                    1
7/10/2020              P1                    7
```

I want to add the interval to each date. for example if the priority is p0 then creationdate+1,

The problem is the date is stored as string.  How can I get the result?

Comment: Date functions are notoriously vendor-specific. Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 2):

First convert string to date using `STR_TO_DATE` function.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10/10/2020', '%m/%d/%y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY;

So 

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(creationdate, '%m/%d/%y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

So if you want to update your query would be

```
UPDATE table_name
SET creationdate = STR_TO_DATE(creationdate, '%m/%d/%y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE Priority = 'P0';
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert string into date please check below answer:

[how to convert a string to date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Considering you are using mssql server.
You can use:
DATEADD(interval, number, date)

Eg:

1. `SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, '2017/08/25') AS DateAdd;`
   Will add 1 year in date,
2. `SELECT DATEADD(date, 1, '2017/08/25') AS DateAdd;`
   Will add 1 day in date.

Considering you are using MySQL:

Syntax:
`DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL value addunit)`

Eg:
`SELECT DATE_ADD("2017-06-15", INTERVAL 1 DAY);`

Will add 1 day in date.

Comment: the column name is creationdate, and each one has priority and interval, and the date column is stored as sting , do i have to change it to date  first and then do case statmen  on it?

Comment: This answer is for `MSSQL Server`. @RaminRafat, as per question it says `mysql`, please confirm the same

Comment: the error that this returns is about the data type. it says that interval can not be working on sting

Comment: You need to change string into date first

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the string to a date, and then use date arithmetics. Consider:

```
select t.*, 
    str_to_date(creationdate, '%d/%m/%Y') + interval intval day enddate
from mytable t
```

Notes:

- your sample data is ambiguous about the format of the date: it could be `%d/%m/%Y` or `%m/%d/%Y`
- `interval` is nt a good choice for a column name, because it conflicts with SQL keyword `interval` (in MySQL, that's a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)); I renamed the column `intval` in the query