# how to sort data by varchar date in ascending order and time in descending order in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I want to sort data by varchar date in ascending order and time in descending order.

Here is my Table: -

```
 name      date     time
 hulk  30-Nov-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  01-Dec-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  02-Dec-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  01-Dec-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  30-Nov-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  30-Nov-2021 02:10 PM
 hulk  03-Dec-2021 01:34 PM
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `News_Data` 
ORDER BY Date ASC , STR_TO_DATE(Time, '%l:%i %p') DESC;
```

after runing a query we get the result like this:

```
 name      date     time
 hulk  01-Dec-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  01-Dec-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  30-Nov-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  01-Dec-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  02-Dec-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  30-Nov-2021 02:10 PM
 hulk  03-Dec-2021 01:34 PM
```

but i want like this:

```
 name      date     time
 hulk  03-Dec-2021 01:34 PM
 hulk  02-Dec-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  30-Nov-2021 02:20 PM
 hulk  01-Dec-2021 03:20 PM
 hulk  01-Dec-2021 02:23 PM
 hulk  01-Dec-2021 01:15 PM
 hulk  30-Nov-2021 02:10 PM
```

someone can help me to tackle this problem.

Comment: you have to convert the VARCHAR to a DATE, see: [How to convert a string to date in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)  BTW: The ordering in the "but I want like this":  Is this REALLY the wanted order ?

Comment: we already try this code but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please stop using "it doesn't work". Show what you really tried, and tell why the output is different from what you want to get.

Comment: I got the answer :    https://stackoverflow.com/a/70212781/13552550

Comment: The real issue is storing dates and times as strings in your table. Formatting is a presentation decision not a data type decision. Constantly converting string values to dates and times so that you can sort or search may have very little cost with a tiny test dataset but doing this in large production datasets can be very costly. Avoid getting into a really bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

You nee str_to_date for date column too

```
SELECT * 
FROM `News_Data` 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%d-%b-%Y')  ASC, STR_TO_DATE(Time, '%l:%i %p') DESC;
```

Comment: OP: *sort data by varchar date in **ascending** order and time in descending order*