# MySQL query to select records with date

Tags: mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin

I have a database where `data_fine` is defined as `TEXT` and contains values such as "`25-05-2021`". I need to find all the records between the current date up to 8 days.

I tried the following query, but nothing is displayed.

```
SELECT * from tabella_raw where data_fine > DATE(NOW) and data_fine < DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 8 DAYS)
```

What is the best and safe way to compare the date stored as `TEXT` with the current date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to date in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201383/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-mysql)

Comment: Partially, the @nbk answer was the correct one I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert dates which cost a lot of processor time, so you should avoid that and save all in MySQL date yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

Also you can use CURDATE() to get the the current date

Last the parameter fo INTERVAL IS `DAY`not  DAYS

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("25-05-2021",'%d-%m-%Y');
SELECT * from tabella_raw where STR_TO_DATE(data_fine,'%d-%m-%Y') > Curdate() and STR_TO_DATE(data_fine,'%d-%m-%Y') < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 DAY;
```

Comment: in this case it is a FULL TABLE SCAN and no index is used

Comment: i doubt that he has a key `
 
BLOB/TEXT column 'data_fine' used in key specification without a key length
?`` or else he would have switched

Answer (score 1):

Try use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

```
SELECT * from tabella_raw where STR_TO_DATE(data_fine, '%d-%m-%Y')  > DATE(NOW) and STR_TO_DATE(data_fine, '%d-%m-%Y') < DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 8 DAYS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a text field as a date, so you need to convert the text to a date to use date functions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).