# Convert string to date in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have a string b = "25/06/2013";
And I want to convert it to stored in SQL Server (data type=date) June, 25, 2013. 
Please advise me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908394/mysql-using-a-string-column-with-date-text-as-a-date-field

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether this is fine,

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, CONVERT(DATE, '25/06/2013', 104)) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CONVERT(DATE, '25/06/2013', 104), 107), 9) AS Date_format
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server provide convert(), you have to store your data in varchar then use this function

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' +
       DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + 
       RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)), 2) AS [DD Month YY]
```

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 0):

WIll this work,

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

DECLARE @DT VARCHAR(15) = '26/05/2014'
SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH,CAST(@DT AS DATETIME)) +','+
    CAST(DATEPART(DAY,CAST(@DT AS DATETIME)) AS VARCHAR(2))+','+
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,CAST(@DT AS DATETIME)) AS VARCHAR(4)) Dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below link of convert function which can be used:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this useful extension method:

`public static string ToSqlString(this DateTime dt)
        {
            return "CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + dt.Year + "-" + dt.Month + "-" + dt.Day + " " + dt.Hour + ":" + dt.Minute + ":" + dt.Second + "." + dt.Millisecond + "', 21 )";
        }`

Answer (score 0):

just check the below. There is format option available for as below link

Different dateformat in sqlserver :- http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

you just change the 113 to desired value format as above in link.

declare @d datetime = getdate()

select CONVERT( varchar(11) , @d , 113)