# Convert TEXT to Date in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, date, search, sql-server-2012

I have a TEXT in this format `31/10/15`.

How do I convert this into a DATE format?

As I need to let the user search from data using a date range.

example: From `15/7/13` to `31/10/15`

Or is there a way to so without converting to date?

Comment: You need specify RDMBS each db have differences regarding `dates`

Comment: In the future, please ask separate questions as separate questions.

Comment: It's also unclear whether "TEXT" refers to character or string data generally or to the specific `text` data type. Judicious formatting of code as code is helpful for better understanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to date in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864535/convert-string-to-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Becuzz Why would you link to a possible duplicate *that's closed as a duplicate*??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Server string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: @KennyEvitt There are about a hundred different ones.  That one's dates had the format closest to the OPs.

Comment: @Becuzz Sorry; I just found it funny. I flagged this as a duplicate of the duplicate-parent of the one to which you linked. There's no reason to have a separate question for each format. The documentation is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONVERT()` for this:

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(50) = '31/10/50'
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @d,3)
```

Note that with a 2-digit year SQL Server will make the year start with '19' for 50 and up, and 49 and below will be '20'

Storing as a `DATE` field will allow easier comparisons, otherwise you'll have to perform this conversion at each step.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.110).aspx); example:

`SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(date, '31/10/15', 3);`

And yes, it's possible to search dates in the same format as the examples you provide, but don't do that – use the proper data types in both your queries and your table columns.