# SELECT range of date in Text field

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   Date

    9/25/2015
    9/26/2015
    9/27/2015
    9/28/2015
    9/29/2015
    9/30/2015
    10/1/2015
    10/2/2015
    10/3/2015
    10/4/2015
    10/5/2015
```

Can anyone help me in MySQL. I would like to select only date from `9/28/2015` to `10/4/2015`.

Please take note, this date is in Text field.

Thank you.

Comment: Use date datatype, not text...

Comment: Is your date stored as varchar or as date?

Comment: Currently it is in Text, i can't change the datatype

Comment: Yes. Don't use a string data type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y')` to convert text to date and you can later use between clause to restrict output data.

Comment: EDIT: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908394/mysql-using-a-string-column-with-date-text-as-a-date-field

Comment: Thank you @PK20 your refer really helpful and i manage to get the answer.

SELECT `Date` as ConvDate FROM `table` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%c/%e/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('9/28/2015', '%c/%e/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%c/%e/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('10/4/2015', '%c/%e/%Y') GROUP BY date(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%c/%e/%Y')) ORDER BY date(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%c/%e/%Y'))

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
WHERE `Date` BETWEEN CAST('9/28/2015' AS DATE) AND CAST('10/4/2015' AS DATE)
```

or

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('9/28/2015', '%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('10/4/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc70cc/3)

Also try to avoid storing dates as Text. Instead use Date datatype to store dates.

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Comment: @AlexLoh:- Updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0047 seconds.)

Date
NULL

Comment: @AlexLoh:- Try this: `select * from test 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('9/28/2015', '%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('10/4/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')` Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc70cc/3

Comment: already found my answer
SELECT `Date` as ConvDate FROM `table` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%c/%e/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('9/28/2015', '%c/%e/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%c/%e/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('10/4/2015', '%c/%e/%Y') GROUP BY date(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%c/%e/%Y')) ORDER BY date(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%c/%e/%Y'))

Thank you for help :)

Comment: @AlexLoh:- Oh..great. Also as recommended. try to avoid storing dates in Text datatype. Just for future prospective. Happy coding.

Comment: If i have the choice, i will store it in date datatype. but for this situation, i don't have any choice, it only had to be in Text datatype

Comment: @AlexLoh:- You can run an ALTER table command and change the datatype. Actually why I am asking you to do that as it would help you in future as well.(*Not trying to debate or argue just a recommendation*)

Comment: I understand that you are recommending a best scenario for me, but at this time i can't alter table. Anyway, you kind response is truely helpful for me to solve the issue. Thank you very much again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert first your dates using `CONVERT`, then use `BETWEEN` in your `WHERE` clause.

Try this..

```
    SELECT * FROM TableName 
    WHERE Date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,'9/28/2015') AND CONVERT(DATE,'10/4/2015')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , in where clause used function str_to_date

```
SELECT `dateVal`,`id` 
 FROM `datecheck` 
  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`dateVal`,'%m/%d/%Y') between STR_TO_DATE('9/28/2015',
 '%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('10/4/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: @Alex Loh hope this solution helps you.No need of converting values in db

Answer (score 0):

I had the same type of issue but in my case the date stored also contains the time (also in a text field, for instance 2017-09-11 05:07:58 PM). This is for a wordpress site but I want to query the database directly, the date is in a meta_value.
To make this work I ended using a subbstring of the date, i am posting this in case it helps someone:

```
SELECT ID, display_name, user_email, meta_value FROM bfge_users, bfge_usermeta WHERE (bfge_users.ID = bfge_usermeta.user_id) AND meta_key ='user_login' AND CAST(SUBSTR(meta_value,1,POSITION(' ' IN meta_value)) AS DATE) between '2017-09-11' AND '2017-09-13';
```

Answer (score -1):

use **between**, you can read more here:

[Select data from date range between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208958/select-data-from-date-range-between-two-dates)

and question is dublicate

Comment: If my datatype is in date, no problem to use between. But my issue now is datatype is in Text

Comment: This only works if the date is stored in a date column. It is unclear if the OP stored it in a varchar column