# PHP MySql Query get get all info with dateencode between 'October-01-2015' and 'December-31-2015'

Tags: php, mysql

please help me.

i have database with "dateencode" field.

but the date value of my "dateencode" field is text.

sample value of the field.

"October-01-2015"
"November-31-2015"
"December-31-2015"

now my problem is i want to get all info with dateencode between 'October-01-2015' and 'December-31-2015'

here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `cu_dateencode` BETWEEN 'October-01-2015' AND 'December-31-2015'
```

this query didnt get any result.

when i try this query

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `cu_dateencode` BETWEEN 'October-01-2015' AND 'October-31-2015'
```

i get result with value October but the problem is i also get year 2014.

please help me

i want to get all info with dateencode between 'October-01-2015' and 'December-31-2015'.

Comment: try this SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `cu_dateencode` BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-12-31'

Comment: no result because the value of the cu_dateencode  field is text like this October-01-2015

Comment: that may be your problem.change it to date type...

Comment: no time to change because the table have many value. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT range of date in Text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164424/select-range-of-date-in-text-field)

Comment: You can typecast this datetext to date then use between. Here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(`cu_dateencode`,'%M-%d-%Y') FROM `customer`  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`cu_dateencode`,'%M-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-12-31'
```